# How to handle promotional content that makes use of database data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, promotions

I am using Ruby on Rails and I would like to render a web page that makes use of database data for promotional purposes. The source code is stated something like the following:

```
# Model
PROMO_ID = 9

# Controller
@promo_article = Article.find(PROMO_ID)

# View
<%= @promo_article.title %>
<%= @promo_article.content %>
```

In the above code I "simply" look for an object instance (a promotional one) relating a database record and then I render it in the view. However, by using the above code, I have to ensure the record existence (that having the `id` equal to that stated for `PROMO_ID`) as a requisite, otherwise the application may raise errors.

I am in trouble because, in order to make the page to work, the record must be present in both development and production database and its reference `PROMO_ID` may differ since in development it may be `9` (as in the above code) and in production it may be `378`.

I thought of using mock objects for my purposes but I would like to use a database record because this way the "promotional" record can be further processed by users. I am looking for a balanced and lean solution to the issue.

What do you advice about? How should I proceed? Should I state some `id` constants or use mock objects?

Comment: I've seen this question before, it seems. Edit question to clarify it, don't recreate it. And I still don't get the definition of "promotional content". What logic should it follow?

Comment: Does only 1 article can be promotional? Should you be able to change promotional article to other one? How do you chose that id?

Comment: @D-side - The logic is that the promo article'd be used by users as well as for promotional purposes and I would like to have one only article record in the database.

Comment: @Rustam A. Gasanov - The plan is to have more than one promotional article. Other users should not be able to change that article, only admins can do. I chose that `id` according to the presence of the related record in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something less rigorous than `find`.

```
# in model
def self.december_promo
  find_by(title: 'December 2014 Promo') }
end

# in controller
@promo_article = Article.december_promo
```

`find_by` will be nil if it does not find the record.

Comment: I usually try to avoid hard-coding IDs into the application itself. What if production and staging fall out of sync? If a human has to play with IDs, consider making a [surrogate ID column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). If this particular feature is very well-controlled, though, ID can do fine do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use Case expression

```
case Rails.env
  when "development"
    PROMO_ID = 9
  when "production"
    PROMO_ID = 378
end
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But there is some more underlying (e.g., certainly some drawbacks)... I am asking even for that other than the solution.